# Delete route not getting any data Laravel 6.X

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, http-delete

I tried changing the routes and using a specific name and several things in the action attribute but there is no way the data doesn't appear when I use the form for the delete and the dd() function on my delete route
[here is what the dd shows me, no info at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6YRM.png)

**My routes:**

```
Route::get('/home/Collections', 'CollectionController@index')->name('collection.index');
Route::get('/home/Collections/{Collection}', 'CollectionController@show')->name('collection.show');
Route::get('/home/Collections/{Collection}/edit', 'CollectionController@edit')->name('collection.edit');
Route::put('/home/Collections/{Collection}', 'CollectionController@update')->name('collection.update');
Route::get('/home/Collections/crear', 'CollectionController@create')->name('collection.create');
Route::delete('/home/Collections/{Collection}', 'CollectionController@destroy')->name('collection.destroy');
Route::post('/home/Collections', 'CollectionController@store')->name('collection.store');
```

**My controller:**

```
public function destroy(Collection $collection)
{
    $collection->delete();
    return redirect('/home'.'/Collections');
}
```

**and my form:**

```
@foreach ($collections as $collection)
<div id="{{$collection->id}}">
    <img/>
    <p>{{$collection->name}}</p>
    <p>{{$collection->description}}</p>
    <form action="/home/Collections/{{$collection->id}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <input type="submit" value="ELIMINAR" class = "btn btn-outline-danger mt-2">
    </form>
</div>
@endforeach
```

my collection model:

```
class Collection extends Model implements Searchable
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'user_id', 'category_id', 'certificate_id', 'img_id'];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
    public function certificate()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Certificate::class);
    }
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::class);
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function getSearchResult(): SearchResult
    {
        $url = route('collection.show', $this->id);

        return new SearchResult(
            $this,
            $this->name,
            $url
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Something interesting is that you're looping over `$collections`, and generating the routes based on `$collection->id` (3 in your `dd()` example), but then navigating to that URL, and doing a `dd($collection)` shows `+exists: false`; that should be `true`, and you should be getting a 404 error if a `Collection` model can't be found for that `id`. Can you post your `Collection` model?

Comment: Also, side note, `'/home'.'/Collections'`; you don't need that `.`; can just be `'/home/Collections'`

Comment: Also try making a route and bind the model `action="{{ route('collection.destroy', ['Collection' => $collection]) }}"`

Comment: thanks Tim Lewis, i will change my code due to your side note ;)
I also just tried binding the model and it doesnt work, keeps telling me there is no data sent

Comment: im not using resource routes cause my team decided to do it as shown, using the name routes

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved a while ago, i forgot to reply to this post.

Solved it changing the Routes URL so they dont match, it seems there was a problem with them even tho it was working like exposed on another project.